# datepicker() function of jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, xhtml, datepicker

I have added `datepicker()` function to my form element with `id=fromDate`

**AllocateTask.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="/webpages/templates/MainTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="infomationPartOfBody">
        <h:form>
            <div class="infoContent">
                <table class="login">
                    <tr>
                        <td><h:outputLabel value="Task to be Allocated"></h:outputLabel></td>
                        <td><h:inputText id="subtaskid" value="#{allocateTaskBean.taskID}"/></td>    
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h:outputLabel value="Employee for the Task"/></td>
                        <td><h:inputText id="empid" value="#{allocateTaskBean.empID}"/> </td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td><h:outputLabel value="From"/></td>
                        <td><h:inputText id="fromDate" value="#{allocateTaskBean.fromDate}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h:outputLabel value="To"/</td>
                        <td><h:inputText id="toDate" value="#{allocateTaskBean.toDate}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h:commandButton value="Allocate" action="#{allocateTaskBean.allocateTask}" ></h:commandButton></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <!--<td> <h:message value="{allocateTaskBean.messagePrint}"/> </td>-->
                    </tr>
                </table>        
            </div> 
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**My JQuery file (JQueryFile.js):**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $("#loginWindow").hide();
    $(".reportItems").hide();
    $("#fromDate").datepicker();

    $("#loginSlide").click(function()
    {
        $("#loginWindow").slideToggle(200);
    });

    $(".reportMenu").click(function()
    {
        $(".reportItems").slideToggle(150);
    });      
});
```

Now as I have used templates, the script have been added to the head of the template file: `MainTemplate.xhtml`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <f:view>
        <h:head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScriptPages/JQueryFile.js"></script>

            <title>State Transport Department- Work Schedule</title>
            <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/CompleteTemplateCSS.css"/>
            <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/templateCSS.css"/>
        </h:head>

// The rest of the content
```

### My Problem

When I click on the text field with `id=fromDate` the calendar is not sliding down and appearing. I can't figure out where the problem is.

The **generated source code** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="j_idt2">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js">  </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery- ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScriptPages/JQueryFile.js"></script>

        <title>State Transport Department- Work Schedule</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/CompleteTemplateCSS.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/templateCSS.css" /></head>
  <body>

<div class="infoContent">
<table class="login">
 <tr>
            <td><label>From</label> </td>
            <td><input id="j_idt26:fromDate" type="text" name="j_idt26:fromDate" /></td>
        </tr>

</table> </div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated source?

Comment: view-source:http://localhost:8084/WorkAllocationSystem/webpages/AllocateTask.xhtml?jftfdi=&jffi=%2Fwebpages%2FAllocateTask.xhtml

Comment: Are you being able to view this? Source is really long to be posted in the comments section

Comment: No, localhost is only accessible on your (local) machine. You could post the HTML in your question or on a site like jsfiddle.com

Comment: i have added it to the questions. Kindly see. Thank You. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your framework (jsf-2) is changing the ID of the element.

You could either use the generated ID in your javascript or just use a class:

```
<td><h:inputText id="fromDate" value="#{allocateTaskBean.fromDate}" class="datetime"/></td>
```

and

```
$(".datetime").datepicker();
```

Comment: Oh dear! It occurred to me once that jsf changed the id, but i interpretted that it would somehow change it for jQuery as well. Thank you soo much!! it is working now!! :) It is not showing the perfect ui for the calender though, showing just a few dates which i can select. Do i need to add some theme script for that?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the jQueryUI datepicker. By default it only shows the current month. You can also show more than one: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars

Comment: actually it is working perfectly fine, showing all the dates months etc. only that it is not showing the nice styling that is applied.

Comment: Then you just need to add the jQueryUI CSS. There are several themes. You can preview the defaults here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ (select "Gallery" on the left). You can host it on your server or use the CDN (as you do with the JS): http://code.jquery.com/ui/